# Symfony2 - Openshift " PHP Fatal error: Class 'HWI\\Bundle\\OAuthBundle\\HWIOAuthBundle' not found

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, openshift, hwioauthbundle

I've been trying to create a simple Symfony 2.5 Project with HWI Oauth bundle .

The projects **works perfectly on my local Windows Machine**  I managed to do facebook Oauth Authentification

But i uploaded my project to an Openshift server and i keep getting this error

**" PHP Fatal error:  Class 'HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle' not found in /var/lib/openshift/5395dfb2500446b159000374/app-root/runtime/repo/symfo/app/AppKernel.php on line 21"**

Same problem with a personnal debian server .
I can't update my project with composer because of that , neither can I do

```
php composer.phar install
```

Both are blocked .
So i did a new project from sractch , added the package to the composer.json , and did a composer install on the server . Still same problem .

I tend to think either it's a case sensitive problem , but i double-checked and i can't find where. Or either I need to register this bundle somewhere else in my project . But i have no idea where .

Also when i **Push my project with git** to my openshift server , the whole project gets uploaded , but **not the HWI Bundle** . I dont know why ...
[image: composer.json]

Comment: If it works on Windows and not on a linux server, the issue is almost certainly file name case sensitivity.

Comment: Could you add the `composer.json` file for the fresh install that didn't work?

Comment: @Phil "the issue is almost certainly file name case sensitivity", how is that possible ? The bundle was added automatically by composer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my problem .

Here is the thing , 
 When i uploaded my project with GIT GUI , **git didn't uploaded the custom bundles** . Therefore , those bundle **could not be found by symfony , and by the kernel itself** .

In order to resolve that , i connected trough SFTP with **FileZila** via this tutorial from Openshift

- [Using FileZila with Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/using-filezilla-and-sftp-on-windows-with-openshift)

After succesfuly logging trhough SFTP upload your full project under repo

> /app-root
>
> > /repo
> >
> > > /mysymfonyproject

As it is done via SFTP the upload is extremly slow (1 hour for me)

Once it is done , just connect via SSH to your terminal and restart all your gears.

```
ctl_all restart
```

Your project just works just fine